# Look for an amount of substring in a file Java

Tags: java, string, file, fileinputstream

I am looking for an amount of substring in a file
In brief, the file contains a certain amount of article, and I need to know how many.
Each article starts with: @ARTICLE{
or with @ARTICLE{(series of integer)

Useful infos:
- I have 10 files to look in
- No files are empty
- This code gives me a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//To read through all files
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
    try
        {       
            //To look through all the bib files
            reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:/Assg_3-Needed-Files/Latex"+i+".bib"));
            System.out.println("Reading Latex"+i+".bib->");

            //To read through the whole file
            while(reader.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = reader.nextLine();
                String articles = line.substring(1, 7);

                if(line.equals("ARTICLE"))
                    count+=1;
            }
        }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error opening the file Latex"+i+".bib");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n"+count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using `String#contains` on each line:

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    if (line.contains("ARTICLE")) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

This would at least get around the problem of having to take a substring in the first place.  The problem is that while matching lines should not have the out of bounds exception, nor should lines longer than 7 characters which don't match, lines having fewer than 7 characters would cause a problem.

You could also use a regex pattern to make sure that you match `ARTICLE` as a standalone word:

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("\\bARTICLE\\b")) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

This would ensure that you don't count a line having something like `articles` in it, which is not your exact target.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if line starts with needed sequence:

```
if (line.startsWith("ARTICLE")) {
    count += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an StringIndexOutOfBounds from this line of code:

```
String articles = line.substring(1, 7);
```

The line read in can be empty or have less than 7 characters.  To avoid getting the StringIndexOutOfBounds you should have a conditional check to see if the

**line.length > 7**

Aside from that then its better to use the answers recommended above (ie **.contains** or **.startsWith**)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading line by line so, string.contains is good choice instead of substring, on the other hand all article start with **"@ARTICLE"**, Therefore use **"@ARTICLE"** in condition. For code test, please try this -

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            try {
                //To look through all the bib files
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:/Assg_3-Needed-Files/Latex" + i + ".bib"));
                System.out.println("Reading Latex" + i + ".bib->");

                //To read through the whole file
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = reader.nextLine();
                    if (line.contains("@ARTICLE")) {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("Error opening the file Latex" + i + ".bib");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n" + count);
    } }
```